# xlsxwriter: Create multiple sheets as per dataframe sorted values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

What would be the alternative to create multiple sheets in an Excel workbook based on SORTED values from dataframe? In this specific case, I would like to create multiple sheets in Excel for each Name sorted by Sex and Height.

The code below returns an "unhashable type: 'list' " type of error as lists cannot be sorted.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as xl

dictionary = {"Name": ["Peter", "John", "Paula", "Simon", "Jess"],
             "Sex": ["M", "M", "F", "M", "F"],
            "Height": [190, 175, 178, 182, 163]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)


wsname = "Test Excel Sheet.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(wsname, engine = "xlsxwriter")
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets
df.sort_values(["Sex", "Height"], ascending =[False, False]).to_excel(writer)

# Create sorted (by Sex and Height) sheets for each Name in the output spreadsheet
names = df["Name"].sort_values(["Sex", "Height"], ascending =[False, False])

for name in names:
    workbook.add_worksheet(name)

writer.save()
```

Is there a possibility to loop through the already exported results from the dataframe instead?

Comment: Have you tried: ```names = df.sort_values(["Sex", "Height"], ascending =[False, False])["Name"]``` ?

Comment: In your for loop, have you tried ```for name in names:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{name}')``` ?

Comment: Corralien, 

This works for me, thank you.